# Change Visual studio 2010 color palette

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I really like Visual studio. I think it is awesome IDE ever been made for developers. But color scheme in new VS2010 is really ugly, so the first thing i'd like to do after install is to change its color palette. I googled how to do this and found VS extension by [Matthew Johnson [MSFT].](http://blogs.msdn.com/visualstudio/archive/2010/01/04/changing-visual-studio-s-color-palette.aspx)
If you know another way to change color palette in VS2010, please let me know.

Comment: If you already found a solution, why ask the question? What's wrong with the solution provided that makes it unsuitable?

Comment: Maybe somebody knows solution that do not use vs extensions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Visual Studio Color Theme Editor](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/20cd93a2-c435-4d00-a797-499f16402378) to make changes directly within Visual Studio, which will allow you to change the theme/color of the actual Visual Studio shell itself.

To change the theme/color of the editor, you can browse themes (created by others) at [Studio Styles](http://studiostyles.info/), which also allows you to create a theme online and then import it into Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

You can create, import and export VS themes in your browser! http://studiostyles.info/

I suppose It should work and for VS 2010

Let me know if it works...

s

Comment: Those are *editor* color themes, not "VS" color themes (which is what Matt's extension lets you change).

Comment: Yes you are right noahric. Vokinneberg already has found this extension. All The Best...