# How can I change the color of the debugger execution point icon in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, user-interface, visual-studio-debugging

Is there any way to change the color of the execution point arrow icon in the Visual Studio 2010 debugger?

I'm talking about the pale yellow arrow that goes in the left margin at the line where the execution pointer currently is.  My problem is that its contrast against the very light gray background of the margin is very poor and I sometimes have a hard time spotting the arrow.

I didn't see any way in the visual studio settings to allow this change, and while I found this [Change Visual studio 2010 color palette](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727506/change-visual-studio-2010-color-palette) which links to a vs theme editor allows changing themes for a lot of the VS UI elements - it doesn't seem to affect the debugger margin icons or the margin color itself.

Answer (score 3):

Yep, Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors > under "Display Items:", choose "Current Statement". 
Just did it myself :-)