# Visual Studio Custom editors

Tags: visual-studio-2010, syntax-highlighting

I wanted to make my own editor in Visual Studio IDE
Where can I start from?
Im trying to have my own syntax highlighting and compiler

Comment: are you trying to make your own project type and compiler?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727506/change-visual-studio-2010-color-palette

Comment: @Steffe No, Im trying to make my own project template and syntax highlighting and compiler. Imagine something like a new language inside VS2010 IDE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is to make a new **Visual Studio Project template**
Here you can read more about it  : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6db0hwky.aspx